# Why does this switch case always return 0?

Tags: c, switch-statement

Here is a simple menu. The user is prompted to select a number between 0 and 3. When running this, if I were to input 1 at the prompt, it would output "Hello2" which is correct. However, at line 9 when it is supposed to return the value 1 (the number input stored as 'type' variable, it returns 0. It will return 0 for any value entered. Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int type;

int main(int argc)
{
    int a = 7;
    getInput();
    printf("You selected: %d\n", type);
}    

int getInput(type)
{
    printf("\nPlease select an option:\n1)Create a record\n2)Display records\n
             3)Update records\n4)Exit\n\n;");
    scanf("%d", &type); 

    switch(type)
    {
        case 0:
        printf("Hello\n");
        break;
        case 1:
        printf("Hello2\n");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("Case3\n");
        break;
        case 3:
        printf("Exit\n");
        break;
        default:
        printf("\nERROR! Please select a valid number\n");    
    }    
}
```

Comment: To avoid this error , use function prototypes. Your code is illegal in C99 (in which functions must at least be declared before using them).

Comment: Do not ignore the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your code is not compilable in the modern C language. Function `getType` is not declared at the point of the call. C language does not allow you to call undeclared functions.

Also this

```
int getInput(type)
{
   ...
```

Is an old K&R-style function definition, which relies on "implicit `int`" rule. Modern C language does not have "implicit `int`" rule anymore, which is why your code is not valid.

Secondly, if your compiler accepts the call and the K&R-style definition, it accepts it as C89/90 code with parameter type defaulting to `int`. This local parameter `int type` is what you are working with. It is not in any way related to the global variable `type`, which remains `0` forever.

Thirdly, your code is broken in many other ways. You defined function `getInput` with a parameter, but call it without any arguments. This causes undefined behavior.

Fourthly, while not immediately an error in C, your `getInput` is declared as returning `int`, but you never return anything from it.

Comment: Also `int main(int argc)` is not a valid declaration for `main` in C89.

Answer (score 1):

The `type` you are modifying is a local variable in `getInput`. If you want to modify the global one, remove the function parameter:

```
int getInput(void) { .... }
```

Also make sure to return something from `getInput`, or make the return type `void`:

```
void getInput(void) { .... }
```

A good solution would be to remove the global variable and return `type` from the function. Fixing that and other problems:

```
int getInput(void)
{
  int type = 0;
  /* 
     as before 
  */

  return type;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = getInput();
    printf("You selected: %d\n", a);
}
```

**Note** The function signature `int getType(type)` has an implicit parameter type `int` in c89, but is invalid from c99 onwards.